# How to write common validation function in Android?

Tags: android, validation, customvalidator

I am working on `Login` and `Register` page for my application.

Both Screen I have email and password field, for validate `email address` and `password` I wrote function in login activity and register activity.

Here both validation are the same code but activity was different, how can I simplify my code with common validate function.

Is it possible, please help me.

Comment: Selvam, check out my answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36419337/3286489. I suggested a simple way of doing that. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to achieve this I believe. One simple way is to write a static function in a Util Class, e.g.

```
 public class ValidationUtil {

    public static boolean validateEmail(String email) {
         boolean result = true;
         // Do your validation and return the result
         return result;
    }

    public static boolean validatePassword(String password) {
         boolean result = true;
         // Do your validation and return the result
         return result;
    }
}
```

The calling side is simple, just use

```
if (ValidationUtil.validateEmail(email)) {
      // ... proceed
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Make one class name with BaseActivity and put this validation function in this class.
This is common function for your both field validation.

Ex. public static boolean validate(String youremail) {

```
    //Code for check validation
     return true/false;
```

}

Now, extend BaseActivity in both your Login and Register activity.
Use this line to validation your both field. here str stand for email or password.

validate(String Str);

this  line return true or false based on validation of your email and password.